# SVN - The value of 'limit' is too large

Tags: eclipse, svn

Eclipse 2021-12, Java 8

Install plugin svn

Success connects to svn repo.

Here installed plugin

[image]

And use Jdk 8

[image]

But when I use Tab "Team Synchronizing" and select some files to see the delta. I get this error:

```
SVN: '0x00400104: Check HEAD Revision' operation finished with error: Receiver class org.apache.subversion.javahl.types.Depth does not implement the interface java.util.Collection defining the method to be called (org.apache.subversion.javahl.types.Depth is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6b0388bb; java.util.Collection is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
Get log messages for 'http://my_repo/cfg/impl/SoftwareRepositoryServiceImpl.java' failed.
Receiver class org.apache.subversion.javahl.types.Depth does not implement the interface java.util.Collection defining the method to be called (org.apache.subversion.javahl.types.Depth is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6b0388bb; java.util.Collection is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

The value of 'limit' is too large
```

Comment: What svn plugin did you install? The problem seems to be irrelevant to Subversion in general. It's a problem with the plug-in or your Eclipse installation.

Comment: This might be caused by running Eclipse with Java 17 and the SVN plugin (which one with which connector of which version?) being not ready for Java 17 (which is more restrictive than previous Java version). Does [running Eclipse with Java 11](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) help?

Comment: @bahrep  I was updated my post

Comment: _"Eclipse 2021-12, Java 8"_ cannot be true.

Comment: @howlger Can be. I was installed jdk 11 , install Eclipse and then in my java project (In Eclipse) set jdk 8. I was updated my post.

Comment: I don't think the JDKs/JREs installed on your system and used in your projects are related to your issue. Do you run your Eclipse with the Java 17 that is part of Eclipse (what's in your `eclipse.ini`)? Does [running Eclipse with Java 11](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) instead of Java 17 help?